# How to include a static image in the template with SilverStripe 4? $ThemeDir is not working

Tags: silverstripe, silverstripe-4

Can anyone please show me how to include a static image in my template with SilverStripe 4? Because $ThemeDir is not working.

E.g.

```
<img src="$ThemeDir/images/home/admissions.svg"/>
```

is not working.

Comment: ThemeDir support will be added back in 4.0.1 - see https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-framework/issues/6030

Comment: Yes, it will be added back, and for the time being, I've been told to just hard code it path.